# Bad file number during android socket read

Tags: android, sockets, okhttp

guys i m trying to download file from server after sometime it will give this exception.

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
                at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
                at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
                at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
                at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.read(HttpConnection.java:464)
                at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
                at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you cancel the call? It’s possible this exception indicates that the socket has been taken away after a canceled call.

Comment: i didnt cancel call . Some time It is also shows  java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
..... caused by  libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)